# How to fetch substring in required format from a String in java?

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have the String in the below format.

```
"resourceId=/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/resource_name/i=xxxxxxxxx/y=2021/m=03/d=13/h=15/m=00/PT1H.json"
```

I'm trying to fetch the substring in the below manner by ideally splitting the string based on "/" and fetch the first part of string until resource_name :

```
/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/resource_name
```

How to achieve this format either by using substring or regEx in java?

### Edited

In the given string ,resource_name will be substituted with vm_name or akv_name. It will be not be resource_name for ever in the string, have given generic name.

Basically, I need to go until virtualMachines from the start and fetch the resource_name which is appended next to virtualMachines by a slash

Then in this scenario.. how to handle it?

Comment: What is the general syntax you start with?  You give one example, which makes it hard to decide what the general case is supposed to be. Somehow I don't think `s.substring(0,113)` is the exact answer you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

You can use a `Pattern` and `Matcher`, to isolate the data using a regular expression capture.

Or, you can use a `replace` procedure to remove the data you don't want.

Or, finally, you can use an `indexOf` procedure to acquire an end-index for a `substring` method.

Because of the simplicity, I recommend the final option.

Consider the following method, `parse`, which takes the `String` value as the first parameter, and the starting and ending `String` values as the second and third parameter.

```java
String parse(String string, String start, String end) {
    int indexOf = string.indexOf(start);
    return string.substring(indexOf, string.indexOf(end) + end.length());
}
```

And, here is an example of it's usage.

```java
String string = "resourceId=/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/resource_name/i=xxxxxxxxx/y=2021/m=03/d=13/h=15/m=00/PT1H.json";
String value = parse(string, "subscriptions", "resource_name");
System.out.println(value);
```

Output

```
subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/resource_name
```

Comment: edited the question.. resource_name is the generic name which I had given.. Can you please suggest me accordingly ?

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions.
using indexOf:

```java
String input = "resourceId=/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/resource_name/i=xxxxxxxxx/y=2021/m=03/d=13/h=15/m=00/PT1H.json";

// Find the index of "resource_name"
int endIndex = input.indexOf("/resource_name");

// Extract the substring until "resource_name"
String substring = input.substring(0, endIndex);

System.out.println(substring);
```

using replaceAll:

```java
String input = "resourceId=/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/resource_name/i=xxxxxxxxx/y=2021/m=03/d=13/h=15/m=00/PT1H.json";

String regex = "/resource_name.*$";
String substring = input.replaceAll(regex, "");

System.out.println(substring);
```

In my end, it works well. Hope these would give you help.

Comment: edited the post.. resource_name is the generic name which I had given.. Can you please suggest me accordingly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
 String sample = "resourceId=/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/resource_name/i=xxxxxxxxx/y=2021/m=03/d=13/h=15/m=00/PT1H.json";
 StringBuilder subString = new StringBuilder(sample.substring(11, sample.indexOf("/i=xxxxxxxxx"));
 String endString = sample.substring(sample.indexOf("/i=xxxxxxxxx"));
 int lastIndex=subString.lastIndexOf("/");
 new StringBuilder(subString.replace(lastIndex,subString.length(),"/vm_name").append(endString));
```